# OpenX Async Tags

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, openx

We all want to make our site faster, google showed a few samples here: http://code.google.com/speed/articles/html5-performance.html

We use OpenX to serve ads, so, assuming browser supporting (FF3.6+), I presume we can just modify the OpenX ad tag from :

```
<script type='text/javascript'> ... ad codes </script>
```

into

```
<script type='text/javascript' async> ... ad codes </script>
```

Will that do the job?  Is there a better way to load scripts asynchronously?

Comment: If you're allready stuck in this point. I wrote a wrapper over here. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955887/ajaxloading-openx-with-jquery-and-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955887/ajaxloading-openx-with-jquery-and-php "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955887/ajaxloading-openx-with-jquery-and-php")

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately OpenX uses document.write to do most of its work.  This means that it will attempt to write at whatever point in the flow its currently on when the script actually runs.  I've tried changing the OpenX javascript snippet itself to not use document.write, but discovered that the response from OpenX often contains document.writes as well.

Comment: such a shocker that we have to depend on openx for the speed of our web experience.

Answer (score 4):

has anyone tried this with openx tags?

http://jqueryad.web2ajax.fr/