# openX performance - CDN?

Tags: performance, openx

I was wondering whether there are any best practices or if you have any good tips on improving performance of a self hosted openX instance.

Apart from the usual suspects (e.g. tuning apache, php and mySQL), using memcached for caching etc.

Is there any room for a CDN or other proxy cache in front of openX? (my guess is no due to the dynamic nature of the delivery scripts results)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could cache the actual creative (image files, etc.) but you've guessed correctly that caching the scripts isn't going to be a good thing.

Based on some [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770570/how-can-we-keep-openx-from-blocking-page-load) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106782/openx-aysnc-tags), it looks like there's not a whole lot to be done to improve OpenX's performance, unfortunately.

Comment: This does not promise to improve performance of OpenX but it is supposed to be able to defer ads load until after the rest of the page has loaded. Apparently it has been used with openX tags succesfuly. We will give it a go: http://www.web2ajax.fr/2010/10/19/jquery-lazyload-ad-v1-4-new-version-of-defer-ad-plugin/

Comment: I saw that link on another question just yesterday. It does look interesting, because even though it doesn't improve performance it might at least prevent OpenX's performance from blocking rendering of the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer these steps given on openx website, 
[performance tuning](http://www.openx.org/docs/whitepapers/performance-tuning) 
Openx has some problems like it fetches all the banners from system which are matching to zone id, and apply all delivery limitation on them to select right banner for serving.
but you can try given steps in url, and that will improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a CDN.

I'm using a CDN (pull zone with CNAME). And I only set this parameter:

*Configuration > Global Settings > Banner Delivery Settings > OpenX Server Access Paths*

Image Store URL: http:// cdn.yourdomain.com/www/images